# LWC1010: Failed to resolve entry for module when trying to wrap an lwc with aura

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to wrap an lwc inside a aura component to make it available in lightning quick action, but when I tried to push the changes to a scratch org, I am getting the below error. Did anyone encountered and resolved it?

My Aura Component

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader">
    <c:sendSms></c:sendSms>
</aura:component>
```

Error  force-app-core\main\default\aura\SendSMSAura\SendSMSAura.cmp  Compilation Failure

/{namespace}/sendSms/sendSMS.js:0,0 : LWC1010: Failed to resolve entry for module "sendSMS".
ERROR running force:source:push:  Push failed.

I refer some of the questions and change like below, but still getting the issue,

<c:send-Sms></c:send-Sms>
<c:send-sms></c:sendsms>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When wrapping it inside an AURA it should be `<namespace: componentNameWithCamelCase></namespace:componentNameWithCamelCase>`.
So in your case it should be

```
`<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader">
    <c:sendSMS></c:sendSMS>
</aura:component>`
```

Also [LWC directly as quick action](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_action.htm&type=5&release=230) is now in pilot & might be available soon.

Comment: Actually the issue is in the name <c:sendSMS> is working correctly. In the suggestions the lwc populate as <c:sendSms> in the visual studio code causing the error. Strict case sensitive in LWC. Thanks Sachin.